# Can I use "better" as a verb?

Tags: verbs

As my title, can I use "better" as a verb? I have read and known that the word  "better" can be used as a verb. For example, to better your business productivity, you should use ABC technology.

I've also searched in Google and found out some examples regarding the word "better" can be used as a verb.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The first [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/better) I found via Google gives adjective, adverb, noun and verb definitions along with examples. All good dictionaries will tell it can be used as a verb.

Comment: Notwithstanding the encouraging answers, I don't think you should normally speak of "bettering your productivity". Most modern usages of *better* as a verb have the sense of *outdo*, rather than *improve*. A common construction being to *better something [else]*, by surpassing it with your own "something". I think to *better yourself* is an exception to the general tendency.

Comment: Don't know why my question is voted down. People may think it's a studpid question because simply they have never seen the case in which "better" is used as a verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

A common phrase is "trying to better yourself".

Answer (score 6):

Shakespeare, Milton, Keats, Ruskin and Wordsworth did, so I don’t see why you can’t.

Comment: +1: but there is a point where concision becomes unhelpful. Specifically, though many writers used *better*, I don't recall a Shakespearean *better your productivity*.

Comment: What if they're wrong?